# Saving files on Rails with Carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file, carrierwave

I'm using Carrierwave to upload files. When a file is received in the controller, I set it to a model object and save the model.

```
@submission = Submission.new(params[:submission])
@submission.file = params[:submission][:file]
@submission.save
```

Then I see that the file is saved in a directory structure. I assume this configuration sets the directory

uploaders/submission_uploader.rb

```
def store_dir
  "files/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{model.id}/#{mounted_as}/"
end
```

I also receive files from different sources. For example, the user can upload a zip file, then the zip is extracted on the server, and a new submission is created with each extracted file and the same parameters, and it is saved.

In this case, when the file is received not from an upload but from other sources, such as files stored on the server, when the model is saved, is the same directory structure generated as when the file is uploaded?

The reason I'm confused is that according to the [documentation](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave) Carrierwave is a file uploader gem, yet this is more to do with object relational mapping, i.e. saving file fields of model objects to the database.

How can I set different files for submissions and make sure they are saved in the same directory structure as when the file is received from an upload?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

turns out carrierwave is an ORM framework too, so it works.